# How to set first day of week to be Monday?

Tags: locale, calendar

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and have my locale/region set to US. I want to keep my region to US but only change the first day of week to Monday.

How could I do this?

Comment: Can you check in the settings? When (if) you reply please ping me with @nate otherwise I might not see it.

Comment: @Nate there doesn't seem to be an option in the settings to change that

Comment: Ok, I would take a look at this http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/gnome/change-first-day-of-week-to-monday-on-ubuntu-gnome-calendar

Comment: That one seems very outdated `Then restart unity-panel-service: $ killall unity-panel-service`

Comment: does the `sudo locale-gen` command work? run that at the end of https://necromuralist.github.io/posts/changing-the-first-day-of-the-week-in-ubuntu-2004/

Comment: you mean like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv31m.png